# converting from linq var result to another object

Tags: linq

using the following LINQ query I want 'chosen' to be a 'User' object which I know and can manipulate, but it's not. How can I convert it to 'User'?
Thanks

```
Console.Write("User name:");
String nickname = Console.ReadLine();
var loggedin = from user in userList 
               where user.getNickname().Equals(nickname) 
               select user;
```

Comment: what result are you currently getting and what do you want instead?

Comment: now the type is "system.linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator'1. pretty sure that's not excactly the real type but that's what getType() tells me. I want to get 'User' object type (which I defined).

Comment: yes (just edited my prev comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your query returns an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is the type of elements in `userList`.

It seems like you're after the `FirstOrDefault` eager operation to retrieve only a single `User` object if present.

```
var loggedin = (from user in userList 
               where user.getNickname().Equals(nickname) 
               select user).FirstOrDefault();
```

`loggedin` will be `null` if `userList` is empty, or if there is no element satisfying the provided predicate.

---

Using method syntax the same can be accomplished like this:

```
var loggedin = userList.FirstOrDefault(user => user.getNickname().Equals(nickname));
```